# Drawing "pressed" state in custom NSSegmentedCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, subclass

I'm using a version of BGHUDSegmentedCell to draw a HUD-style segmented control (NSSegmentedControl).

However I can't see any way to draw the cell in the "pressed" state while the user is clicking on a segment (so that the user gets proper tracking feedback).  The default NSSegmentedControl/Cell manage this, so there is presumably a way, although being system code, who knows if it is a public way.

The subclass overrides:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)view {
- (void)drawSegment:(NSInteger)segment inFrame:(NSRect)frame withView:(NSView *)view {
```

Is there any way in the NSSegmentedCell to determine that it is drawing a segment in a "pressed" state and so display it appropriately during tracking?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably best to implement your own down/pressed state tracking by overriding NSCell's mouse tracking methods.

```
- (BOOL)startTrackingAt:(NSPoint)startPoint inView:(NSView *)controlView;
- (void)stopTracking:(NSPoint)lastPoint at:(NSPoint)stopPoint inView:(NSView *)controlView mouseIsUp:(BOOL)flag;
- (BOOL)continueTracking:(NSPoint)lastPoint at:(NSPoint)currentPoint inView:(NSView *)controlView;
```

Those in combination with `-(CGFloat)widthForSegment:(NSInteger)segment;` will probably be enough to determine on which segment the mouse is pressed and then render appropriately.

Comment: The startTrackingAt method @arun.s suggested doesn't work because NSSegmentedControl uses a different and unknown tracking area.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this recently and found it was possible to inspect the current mouse event to see if the target segment was pressed. Called from within `drawSegment:inFrame:withView:`:

```
func isSegmentPressed(segment: Int, frame: NSRect, controlView: NSView) -> Bool {
    if let event = NSApp.currentEvent, event.type == .leftMouseDown, isEnabled(forSegment: segment) {
        let location = controlView.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        return frame.contains(location)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Wont that fail if the user clicks on one segment, and drags over a different segment?  Perhaps the system would rarely redraw the second segment at that point, but it could if there was some other reason for a redraw?

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this in `segmentcell` class

```
NSLog(@"selectedSegment - > ",[self selectedSegment]);
```

Check for selected segment index and do things necessary.

Hope this Helps !!!

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  selectedSegment remains unchanged until after the button release and the tracking completes - I want to be able to draw the pressed segment in a "Pressed" state during button tracking. drawWithFrame is called, but I can't find any way to detect which segment is being tracked.

Comment: You can check tracking of segment in these three delegates rt :     - (BOOL)startTrackingAt:(NSPoint)startPoint inView:(NSView *)controlView
- (BOOL)continueTracking:(NSPoint)lastPoint at:(NSPoint)currentPoint inView:(NSView *)controlView
- (void)stopTracking:(NSPoint)lastPoint at:(NSPoint)stopPoint inView:(NSView *)controlView mouseIsUp:(BOOL)flag

Comment: add it as an answer and I'll explain why this doesn't using startTrackingAt et al doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.  It's not ideal, but it does work in my testing and for my case, but it uses the private NSSegmentedCell method:

```
- (NSInteger)_segmentHighlightState:(NSInteger)arg1;
```

This method returns 1 for unselected cells, 3 for unselected cells while they are pressed during tracking, 4 for selected cells, and 5 for selected cell while pressed during tracking.

So testing bit 1 (mask with 0x02) gives the desired "is pressed" state.  Sadly this is useless if you want to ship on the Mac App Store, but since Keyboard Maestro is excluded from the Mac App Store because of the sandboxing requirement, that no longer concerns me.

It is still worth defending against any possible changes, with code like this:

```
- (BOOL) mySegmentIsPressed:(int)segment;
{
    NSInteger highlightState = 0;
    if ( [self respondsToSelector:@selector(_segmentHighlightState:)] ) {
        highlightState = [self _segmentHighlightState:segment];
    } else {
        highlightState = ([self selectedSegment] == segment) ? 4 : 1;
    }
    return (highlightState&2) != 0;
}
```

The startTrackingAt method @arun.s suggested doesn't work because NSSegmentedControl uses a different and unknown tracking area )and besides, even rectForSegment:inFrame is a private method so you can't even really find out where the cell is without using a (less) private method.

I'd rather a documented way to do this, but short of implementing the entire control afresh, I don't see how.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I implemented the press state.

```
- (void) drawSegment:(NSInteger)segment inFrame:(NSRect)frame withView:(NSView *)controlView
    {
        NSColor *startColor = [NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.690196 green:0.690196 blue:0.690196 alpha:1.0];
        NSColor *endColor = [NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.878431 green:0.878431 blue:0.878431 alpha:1.0];
        NSGradient *grad = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:startColor endingColor:endColor];

        if(![self isSelectedForSegment:segment]) {
            [grad drawInRect:frame angle:270];
        }
        [super drawSegment:segment inFrame:frame withView:controlView];
    }
```

In an unpressed state, the segmented control draw a gradient to mimic the background of the toolbar (or window border). I just don't draw when the control is pressed.